# Preview shortcuts to select editor tabs by index

Tags: keyboard, preview

I am trying to switch rapidly back and forth between two related Preview tabs (different versions of a research paper). In other applications I would do this by selecting `Command-[TabNumber]`  e.g. `Command-3` then `Command-4` then back to `Command-3`.

What is the equivalent in `Preview`?  I did look at the help https://support.apple.com/guide/preview/preview-keyboard-shortcuts-on-mac-cpprvw0003/mac
 and also just tried a number of combinations without luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Preview you can do the following:

1. Open the two documents in their windows;
2. Go to menu Window and click on "Merge All Windows"; this will merge the windows into tabs inside Preview.
3. Now you are ready to switch between tabs with `Ctrl+Tab` to go to next tab, or with `Ctrl+Shift+Tab` for previous tab.

Comment: Ah! `Control-Tab` !   Any idea why Preview used a completely non-standard way to do the switching between tabs? Also - is there any way to switch _by number_  as in _chrome_  _intellij_ etc .. or is it necessary to just cycle through all of them..

Comment: the answerer already mentions that

Comment: @javadba if you have many open documents, to switch fast at random to one of them, you just simply click on tab title, or go to menu Window, open it and just check-mark the needed document. You do not need to cycle through all of them. I do not know the reason of this implementation but it is also a standard one (Tab control) and more simpler and more reliable software: it implements just two events to navigate.

Comment: "click" umm the whole point is to use the _keyboard_